# Is it possible to communicate and working on other functionality with azure iot with out using iot-sdk from device to azure iot cloud

Tags: azure-iot-hub

Is it possible to directly communicate and other functionality like desired property, reported property,methods, commands from device to azure cloud with out using azure iot sdk?

Comment: in addition to the above duplicated answer (related only to the uploading file), the device twin functionality to the device-facing endpoint is currently available only for MQTT protocol, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support

Comment: see also https://www.nuget.org/packages/M2Mqtt/. You can use this raw MQTT Client library for building a MQTT device connected to the Azure IoT Hub without using the Device SDKs.